# Programmatically call org-capture w/ specific template

Tags: org-capture

Is it possible to use emacs-lisp to call `org-capture` with some template being preselected?

My use case is:
I need an org-mode External link of ‘elisp’ type that triggers a specific org-capture template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the template would interactively be called with letter `r`, say, then

```lisp
(org-capture nil "r")
```

would do the job.  See the `org-capture` doc-string for more details (you want the section about the `KEYS` argument).